# Autoload is changing Scope of variables included in autoloaded file

Tags: php, scope, include, autoload

I'm having some trouble with my php project...

The autoload function:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
include 'HTMLClasses/'.$class_name . '.php';});
```

When autloloading classes from the "HTMLClasses" directory, the variables in the autoloaded file which are included from other files are not in its scope anymore.

#### someFile.php

```
require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/config/phpFileIndex.php";
require_once $phpFile['resourcesPaths'];
include_once "../autoload.php";
class SomeClass{}
```

the problem now is, that when autoloading this class the **$phpFile** Variable isn't in the scope of this script anymore. It is Global and i can access it by using $GLOBALS but I do not understand why I need this at all, beacause if I include **SomeClass** manualy, the variable is in the normal scope. In the documentation of **spl_autoload_register** there is nothing documented about this behavior.

Another problem is that i can't include autoload from here. Even though the autoload.php is in the upper directory. When including the full path from Document_root it works but not relative. And I actually do not understand this. The warning says:

```
'Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '../autoload.php' for inclusion (include_path='\xampp\php\PEAR') in F:\<path>\HTMLClasses\Template.php on line 4'
```

I dont know if this is a problem with the code or with my enviorment.

I tried searching for it, but the problem is actually, that I don't know what to search for. If anyone has an Idea about this I would really apreciate it. :)

Comment: Try `require_once __DIR__ . '/../autoload.php';`. You need to refer to the `__DIR__` when the path is relative to the current file (otherwise, it will be relative to the currently executed script, which might not be the same).

Comment: Oh boy... Completly forgot about this... Thank you very much. :)

Comment: The scope of the variables are now within the scope of your anonymous function. I would either make these properties of the class, or find some other way to access those variables that is not referencing globals. If these variables are static, make them class constants. If their values change, make them properties.

Comment: Ah ok I understand...
But __$phpFile__ is not in an class. Its just written in the script. 
And I call the require from the someFile.php and not from somewhere else. So when Including __phpFileIndex.php__ the scope of the variables of this file should be in the scope of the phpFile, doesn't it? Because I don't call the variable from outsige but in the next line....